# Aftertaste when making gummies

Tags: candy

We currently make medical marijuana gummies and are experiencing an aftertaste on some batches. People describe it as chemical/metallic/dry. We have been using the same ingredients (modified potato starch, sugar,corn syrup, citric acid, sodium citrate, flavoring and cannabis extract).

Has anyone had any experience with this?

Comment: Indoubt anyone here will be able to answer your question. However, there are general food quality troubleshooting processes you can use to help figure it the source. Is the issue apparent immediately or after some time? Is it correlates with a specific ingredient or not?

Comment: Are you adding citric acid or anything to the sugar before you melt it?

Comment: We pour in the hot mix of modified starch Into room temperature corn syrup. We then pour sugar in and mix until it melts.

Comment: Is it the aftertaste related to a particular flavoring, or independent of flavoring? Have you ever encountered it in a batch without the cannabis extract?

Comment: Why are you using sodium citrate, and have you tried without? This sounds like a very likely culprit, many sodium salts taste metallic..

Comment: The sodium citrate is the sour salt of citric acid (sour tasting) and is used to control ph. I will try without it

Comment: What are you making them in (all phases)? And please [edit] all the additional information into your question as well. Comments can disappear.

Answer (score -1):

If you use a different strain when you make your gummies, that can affect taste and dryness for sure.